# Why did Tree try to stop the closing of the time-loop?

Tags: movie, happy-death-day

In *Happy Death Day 2U* (2019), Tree tries to stop the closing of the time-loop, which is operated 
by Ryan, by driving his car into an electric power grid:

[image]

Why did Tree try to stop the closing of the time-loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first Tree wanted to stay in the reality where her mother never died because she misses her. For that to happen the loop had to come to an end. But she has a change of heart when she learns(listening to the news on the radio) that if the loop doesn't reset Carter will die trying to save Lori and Lori will also die. So she kills herself to get loop restarted so she can save them.